# \eqnarray and \boxed

Tags: equations, boxes

Hey I have following code and I would like to set last equality into box but when I use `\boxed` I have an error. What can I do?

```
\begin{eqnarray*}
    \Theta _{C} &=&\frac{\partial }{\partial t}\left( C\right) =qSe^{-q\left(
        T-t\right) }N\left( d_{+}\right) -rKe^{-r\left( T-t\right) }N\left(
    d_{-}\right)  \\
    &&+Se^{-q\left( T-t\right) }n\left( d_{+}\right) \sigma \frac{-1}{2\sqrt{T-t}%
    } \\
    &=&qSe^{-q\left( T-t\right) }N\left( d_{+}\right) -rKe^{-r\left( T-t\right)
    }N\left( d_{-}\right)\\
    &&-Se^{-q\left( T-t\right) }n\left( d_{+}\right) \frac{%
        \sigma }{2\sqrt{T-t}} \\
\end{eqnarray*}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Never use `eqnarray` under any circumstances; `amsmath` provides several environments for alignments that are more powerful and feature much better spacing.

Here you can use `aligned` nested inside `align*`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\Theta _{C}
   = \frac{\partial}{\partial t}(C)
  &= \begin{aligned}[t]
     &  qSe^{-q(T-t) }N( d_{+}) -rKe^{-r( T-t) } N(d_{-})  \\
     &+ Se^{-q( T-t) }n( d_{+}) \sigma \frac{-1}{2\sqrt{T-t}}
     \end{aligned}
\\[2ex]
  &= \boxed{\begin{aligned}[t]
     & qSe^{-q( T-t) }N( d_{+}) -rKe^{-r( T-t)}N( d_{-})\\
     &-Se^{-q( T-t) }n( d_{+}) \frac{\sigma }{2\sqrt{T-t}}
     \end{aligned}}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

An `aligned` environment can easily be `\boxed`.

[image]

Note that I removed all `\left` and `\right` commands that did nothing useful (and damaged the spacing).

Also, I moved the alignment point to the second “=” in the first line, for better symmetry.

Comment: Thanks it works! :)

Comment: `alignat` -> `aligned`

Comment: @IanThompson Thanks, fixed

Answer (score 4):

First, forget about `eqnarray`/`eqnarray*`. Use `align`/`align*` instead: https://www.texfaq.org/FAQ-eqnarray.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}


\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    \Theta_{C}&=\frac{\partial }{\partial t}\left( C\right)=qSe^{-q\left(
        T-t\right) }N\left( d_{+}\right) -rKe^{-r\left( T-t\right) }N\left(
    d_{-}\right)  \\
    &+Se^{-q\left( T-t\right) }n\left( d_{+}\right) \sigma \frac{-1}{2\sqrt{T-t}%
    } \\
    &=qSe^{-q\left( T-t\right) }N\left( d_{+}\right) -rKe^{-r\left( T-t\right)
    }N\left( d_{-}\right)\\
    &-Se^{-q\left( T-t\right) }n\left( d_{+}\right) \frac{%
        \sigma }{2\sqrt{T-t}} \\
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here there is the boxed formula using `empheq` package.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{empheq}
\begin{document}
\begin{empheq}[box=\fbox]{align*}
    \Theta_{C}&=\frac{\partial }{\partial t}\left( C\right)=qSe^{-q\left(
        T-t\right) }N\left( d_{+}\right) -rKe^{-r\left( T-t\right) }N\left(
    d_{-}\right)  \\
    &+Se^{-q\left( T-t\right) }n\left( d_{+}\right) \sigma \frac{-1}{2\sqrt{T-t}%
    } \\
    &=qSe^{-q\left( T-t\right) }N\left( d_{+}\right) -rKe^{-r\left( T-t\right)
    }N\left( d_{-}\right)\\
    &-Se^{-q\left( T-t\right) }n\left( d_{+}\right) \frac{%
        \sigma }{2\sqrt{T-t}}
\end{empheq}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum 1**: "to set into box only last equation, i.e only last two lines, without "=" sign" (see the comment).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{empheq}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    \Theta_{C}&=\frac{\partial }{\partial t}\left( C\right)=qSe^{-q\left(
        T-t\right) }N\left( d_{+}\right) -rKe^{-r\left( T-t\right) }N\left(
    d_{-}\right)  \\
    &+Se^{-q\left( T-t\right) }n\left( d_{+}\right) \sigma \frac{-1}{2\sqrt{T-t}%
    } 
    \end{align*}
\begin{empheq}[innerbox=\fbox]{align*}
   qSe^{-q\left( T-t\right) }N\left( d_{+}\right) -rKe^{-r\left( T-t\right)
    }N\left( d_{-}\right) &\\
    -Se^{-q\left( T-t\right) }n\left( d_{+}\right) \frac{%
        \sigma }{2\sqrt{T-t}} &
\end{empheq}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum 2**: From the comment of @Barbarabeeton "Where is the equal sign for the boxed material in the last version".

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{empheq}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    \Theta_{C}&=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}(C)=qSe^{-q(
        T-t)}N(d_{+})-rKe^{-r(T-t}N(
    d_{-})  \\
    &+Se^{-q(T-t)}n(d_{+}) \sigma\frac{-1}{2\sqrt{T-t}%
    } 
    \end{align*}
\begin{empheq}[box=\fbox]{align*}
\MoveEqLeft
   =qSe^{-q(T-t)}N(d_{+})-rKe^{-r(T-t)
    }N(d_{-}) \\
   &-Se^{-q(T-t)}n(d_{+}) \frac{%
        \sigma}{2\sqrt{T-t}} 
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I suggest you recommend not using `eqnarray` with the following reference: https://www.texfaq.org/FAQ-eqnarray

Comment: @ivankokan Yes, in the meantime I'm putting the boxed formula. However you can edit my question adding your link if you prefer. Welcome :-)

Comment: but how to take the last equality into box? It has 2 lines

Comment: @HSmile Work in progress :-)

Comment: @ivankokan Thank you very much for your edit.

Comment: @HSmile I have finished :-) my work.

Comment: Thanks but it still doesnt solve my problem. You set all equations into box, but I would like to set into box only last equation, i.e only last two lines, without "=" sign (sign "-" easy to move to the right by `\quad` command but how to put this into box?)

Comment: @HSmile Ah, I'm sorry I have not, as usual, not understood the question.

Comment: @HSmile Can you see if now is better? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your time, it looks ok :) Meanwhile someone propose another solution

Comment: @HSmile Certainly and it is right what you have written.

Comment: Where is the equal sign for the boxed material in the last version?

Comment: @barbarabeeton It is true.